# Where in a .dtx file does \DefineOptions go and what are the rules?

Tags: dtx, options

Given the source of demopkg.dtx:

```
    % \iffalse meta-comment
    % !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
    %<*internal>
    \iffalse
    %</internal>
    %<*readme>
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    demopkg --- description text
    E-mail: you@your.domain
    Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
    See https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Some text about the package: probably the same as the abstract.
    %</readme>
    %<*internal>
    \fi
    \def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
    \ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
      \expandafter\begingroup
    \fi
    %</internal>
    %<*install>
    \input docstrip.tex
    \keepsilent
    \askforoverwritefalse
    \preamble
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    demopkg --- description text
    E-mail: you@your.domain
    Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
    See https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \endpreamble
    \postamble
    
    Copyright (C) 2009 by You <you@your.domain>
    
    This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
    conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
    version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
    version.  The latest version of this license is in the file:
    
    https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
    
    This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
    You.
    
    This work consists of the file  demopkg.dtx
    and the derived files           demopkg.ins,
                                    demopkg.pdf and
                                    demopkg.sty.
    
    \endpostamble
    \usedir{tex/latex/demopkg}
    \generate{
      \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
    }
    %</install>
    %<install>\endbatchfile
    %<*internal>
    \usedir{source/latex/demopkg}
    \generate{
      \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
    }
    \nopreamble\nopostamble
    \usedir{doc/latex/demopkg}
    \generate{
      \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
    }
    \ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
      \expandafter\endbatchfile
    \else
      \expandafter\endgroup
    \fi
    %</internal>
    %<*package>
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesPackage{demopkg}[2009/10/06 v1.0 description text]
    %</package>
    %<*driver>
    \documentclass{ltxdoc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{\jobname}
    \usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
    \EnableCrossrefs
    \CodelineIndex
    \RecordChanges
    \begin{document}
      \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
    \end{document}
    %</driver>
    % \fi
    %
    %\GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
    %
    %\title{^^A
    %  \textsf{demopkg} --- description text\thanks{^^A
    %    This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.^^A
    %  }^^A
    %}
    %\author{^^A
    %  You\thanks{E-mail: you@your.domain}^^A
    %}
    %\date{Released \filedate}
    %
    %\maketitle
    %
    %\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{First public release}
    %
    %\DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
    % Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which
    % might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
    % \marg{arg2}.
    %
    %\StopEventually{^^A
    %  \PrintChanges
    %  \PrintIndex
    %}
    %
    %    \begin{macrocode}
    %<*package>
    %    \end{macrocode}
    %
    %\begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
    %\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{Some change from the previous version}
    %    \begin{macrocode}
    \newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
      Some code here, probably
    }
    %    \end{macrocode}
    %\end{macro}
    %
    %    \begin{macrocode}
    %</package>
    %    \end{macrocode}
    %\Finale
```

Where would I place a \DefineOptions block like:

```
    % \begin{macro}{\ifFN@noemph}
    % Define the |noemph| option: This sets a marker for use later
    % when defining the option's auxiliary code and when patching the
    % output routine and so on.
    %    \begin{macrocode}
    \newif\ifFN@noemph \FN@noemphfalse
    \DeclareOption{noemph}{\relax}
    %    \end{macrocode}
    % \end{macro}
```

I think I'm missing something obvious but as usual I find other's `obvious' to be opaque.

Comment: see `texdoc clsguide` you typically declare options  anywhere between `\ProvidesPackage` at t the of the package and `\ProcessOptions`  which ends the options handling block.

Comment: I tried immediately after \ProvidesPackage and recieved the error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you have double indented the example, it doesn't work at all unless you remove the 4 spaces on each line.

The dtx structure seems more than usually complicated but works, you want to add the options section at the start of the package after `\ProvidesPackage` ending with `\ProcessOptions` so for example

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
----------------------------------------------------------------
demopkg --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

Some text about the package: probably the same as the abstract.
%</readme>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
----------------------------------------------------------------
demopkg --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

\endpreamble
\postamble

Copyright (C) 2009 by You <you@your.domain>

This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
version.  The latest version of this license is in the file:

https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt

This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
You.

This work consists of the file  demopkg.dtx
and the derived files           demopkg.ins,
                                demopkg.pdf and
                                demopkg.sty.

\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{demopkg}[2009/10/06 v1.0 description text]
%</package>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
%
%\title{^^A
%  \textsf{demopkg} --- description text\thanks{^^A
%    This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.^^A
%  }^^A
%}
%\author{^^A
%  You\thanks{E-mail: you@your.domain}^^A
%}
%\date{Released \filedate}
%
%\maketitle
%
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{First public release}
%
%\DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
% Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which
% might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
% \marg{arg2}.
%
%\StopEventually{^^A
%  \PrintChanges
%  \PrintIndex
%}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{macro}{\ifFN@noemph}
% Define the |noemph| option: This sets a marker for use later
% when defining the option's auxiliary code and when patching the
% output routine and so on.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newif\ifFN@noemph \FN@noemphfalse
\DeclareOption{noemph}{\relax}
\ProcessOptions
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
%\begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{Some change from the previous version}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
  Some code here, probably
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\Finale
```

Then running tex on the dtx will extract `demopkg.sty` that looks like

```
%%
%% This is file `demopkg.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% demopkg.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% demopkg --- description text
%% E-mail: you@your.domain
%% Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
%% See https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{demopkg}[2009/10/06 v1.0 description text]
\newif\ifFN@noemph \FN@noemphfalse
\DeclareOption{noemph}{\relax}
\ProcessOptions
\newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
  Some code here, probably
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explicit example! Exactly what I was hoping for!